# Find the integral $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$

Put $x=a\sec\theta\implies dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$
$$
\begin{align}
& \ \ \ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}} \\ 
&=\int \frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\sec^2\theta-a^2}} \\ 
&=\int \frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{a\sqrt{\tan^2\theta}}\\ 
&= \int\frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{a\color{red}{\tan\theta}}\\ 
&=\int\sec\theta d\theta \\ 
&=\log \lvert \sec\theta+\tan\theta \rvert|+C_0 \\ 
& \mbox{where $C_0$ is an arbitrary constant of integration }  \\
&=\log \left\lvert \frac{x}{a}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1} \right\rvert + C_0 \\
&= \log \left\lvert \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{a} \right\rvert +C_0 \\ 
&= \log \left\lvert x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2} \right\rvert -\log|a|+C_0 \\ 
&= \log|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+ C, 
& \mbox{ where $C = \log \lvert a \rvert + C_0$}.
\end{align}
$$
This is how it is solve in my reference. But, $\sqrt{\tan^2\theta}=|\tan\theta|$ right ?
Then, does that imply
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\int\frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{a\color{red}{|\tan\theta|}}=\color{red}{\pm}\int\sec\theta d\theta
$$
Why am I getting this confusion and is the first solution complete ?

Comment: @TrostAft how can i say $\tan\theta$ is $+$ve from $x^2-a^2>0$ ?

Comment: No first solution is not complete, they silently slipped in the || inside. You know,  $\int \sec t = \ln(\sec t + \tan t)$ is valid for $\sec t > 0$ and for $\sec t \lt 0$ the integrand is $\ln(-\sec t - \tan t)$ so the solution $\ln |\sec t + \tan t|$ combines both.

Comment: Check by differentiating your solution(s).

Comment: Agree with @samjoe. My comment is untrue.

Comment: @samjoe i'm srry dont understand how ur point help me with the doubt in OP ?. Could u pls explain bit more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a>0$.

The work is just for the case when $x>a$. The case for $x<-a$ is different, but the finals result is the same.

Let $x=a\sec\theta$, where $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2})\cup(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$. This is the domain of $\textrm{arcsec}$.

For $x< -a$, $\theta\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and so $\tan\theta\le0$.

$$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=\sqrt{a^2\tan^2\theta}=-a\tan\theta$$

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}&=\int\frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta}{-a\tan\theta}d \theta\\
&=-\int\sec\theta d\theta\\
&=-\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C\\
&=\ln|\sec\theta-\tan\theta|+C\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{x}{a}-\frac{-\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{a}\right|+C\\
&=\ln\left|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|-\ln|a|+C
\end{align*}

There are two minus signs and they cancel each other to reach the final result.

Comment: I don't uunderstand how you conclude $\theta \in (\pi/2, \pi]$ because that is the key to the question.

Comment: I mean why it can't be $\theta \in (\pi, 3\pi/2)$ where sec is negative but tan is positive

Comment: Yes thats what we have to show that tan cannot be positive.

Comment: If we take $\theta\in(\pi,3\pi/2)$, then $\tan\theta>0$. The integral is $\int\sec\theta d\theta$. The final answer will be still $\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|-\ln|a|+C$. My point is that we can have $-\int\sec\theta d\theta$ in the work. But then we will have one more minus sign and obtain the same final answer.

Comment: We either take a range so that the work holds for both $x>a$ and $x<-a$, or take a range so that in one case we will have two minus signs to cancel each other.

Comment: $\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right)-\ln a=ArcCosh(x/a)$

Answer (score 0):

This is an elementary integral, using an inverse hyperbolic function.

By the formula for inverse functions, $$\cosh'(x)=\sinh(x)=\sqrt{\cosh^2(x)-1}$$ lets you establish

$$\text{arcosh}'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$

It is known that

$$\text{arcosh}(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$ though the form $\text{arcosh}$ is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Given the known pitfalls of trigonometric substitutions for this integral, substitute $y= \sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ instead. Then, $y\ dy=x\ dx$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}
=& \int \frac{dx}y= \int \frac{(1+\frac xy)dx}{x+y}
=\int \frac{d(x+y)}{x+y}= \ln|x+y|+C
\end{align}
valid all domain $x$.